# Is there a standard combinator packing the result of a lens in functor?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

While trying to apply a function with multiple layers of functors to a member of a host data structure, as in the following example:

```hs
update ::
  (SomeProductField -> Maybe (Int, SomeProductField)) -> 
  (SomeProduct -> Maybe (Int, SomeProduct))
```

I came up with the following utility:

```hs
inFunctor :: Functor f => Lens s t a b -> Lens s (f t) a (f b)
inFunctor lens f = getCompose . lens (Compose . f)
```

Allowing me to implement the `update` function like this:

```hs
someProductFieldLens :: Lens' SomeProduct SomeProductField

update = inFunctor someProductFieldLens
```

I am wondering whether something like this is already present in "lens" and whether the same is achievable somehow otherwise using the existing means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much of a standard approach, perhaps, but anyway: [`alaf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.1/docs/Control-Lens-Wrapped.html#v:alaf) can handle the `Compose` wrapping. For instance:

```
data SomeProduct = SomeProduct
    { _someProductField :: Bool
    , _anotherProductField :: String
    }
    deriving Show
makeLenses ''SomeProduct
```

```
ghci> alaf Compose someProductField (\b -> Just (fromEnum b, not b)) (SomeProduct False "foo")
Just (0,SomeProduct {_someProductField = True, _anotherProductField = "foo"})
```

If you'd still like to define the general combinator:

```
inFunctor :: Functor f => Lens s t a b -> Lens s (f t) a (f b)
inFunctor l = alaf Compose l
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks and happy holidays!

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Happy holidays to you, too :)